# The normal vector's direction of curve on surface

Tags: differential-geometry

Find the Gaussian curvature, $K$ at the point, $p$ of the given surface, $M$.

$M$ : the surface which is rotation of the $x^2 + (y-1)^2=1$ with $x$- axis

Here the $p = ({1 \over 2}, 1-{\sqrt3\over 2}, 0)$

---

The $M$ definitely torus. Hence Only considering principal curvature of the each meridian and latitude circle by the formula $\kappa_n = \kappa <\mathbb{N}, U>$.

($U$ is a unit normal vector of the $M$, $\mathbb{N}$ is a normal vector of curve)

But here is the big problem I've met.

To find the latitude circle's principal curvature

First $\kappa = {2 \over {2- \sqrt3}}$

Second only we find just $cos\theta$ = $<\mathbb{N}, U>$

So I took the $U$(red direction) as the outer direction of the  $x^2 + (y-1)^2=1$ and $T$ as the direction coming up from the screen. ($T$ is tangent vector of the latitude circle)

Then there are 4 cases can be $\mathbb{N}$ (Please confer the below picture. It was marked by blue vectors.)
[image]

Which one is the direction of the $\mathbb{N}$ ? And What is the reason of that?

(Are there any ways for finding the $\mathbb{N}$ vector?)

Comment: This is actually not a smooth surface. It's a pinched torus, where the hole in the middle has been collapsed.  However, it *is* a smooth surface in a neighborhood of the point $p$. I don't understand your picture. The normal to the latitude circle has to be in the plane of the latitude circle, right? So that leaves $N_2$ or $N_4$, and it must point toward the center of the circle, so that leaves ...

Comment: Sorry for Mr @TedShifrin, I have a serious typo for the point $p$ in my question. I revised that. Anyway let me explain about my picture. First, the point $p$ is intersection point between circle and $U$ vector(red vector). Second, $T$ tangent vector of the latitude circle at the point, $p$ which is generated by the $x$-axis would be direction coming out from the screen. Third, my question was what is the normal vector of the latitude circle among 4-blue vector, $N_i$ for given tangent vector, $T$.

Comment: Also Thanks to your support, I've got the idea $N_3$ and $N_1$ aren't normal to the latitude circle. Then there are two candidates becoming the normal. My guess is $N_4$ because the latitude circle for the $p$ is circle itself whose center is on the $x$-axis. But I don't have a confidence that my guess is right or not.